# Semantic difference in C++, defining a constant data instance

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax

Do the following four different syntax do the same thing when initializing a constant data member, of type int for example, in C++ 11? If not, what is the difference?

```
{
    const int a = 5; //usual initialization, "=" is not assignment operator here it is an initialization operator.
}
{
    const int a(5); //calling the constructor function directly
}
{
    const int a = {5}; //similar to initializing an array
}
{
    const int a{5}; //it should work, but visual studio does not recognizing it
}
```

Why is the fourth one not recognized by Visual Studio as a valid statement?

Comment: okay, I am using visual studio 2012 and am getting the following errors:

'1- error C2734: 'a' : const object must be initialized if not extern'
'2-error C2601: 'a' : local function definitions are illegal'
'3-this line contains a '{' which has not yet been matched'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are all valid and the same in Visual Studio 2013 (the last one is not valid in VS2012 as @remyabel suggested).

The two `{...}` syntaxes can differ from the others in what constructor is called for a type, but the type `int` **uses no constructor**.

They will **differ** when constructing a class that accepts a `std::initializer_list<T>`.

Take, for example, this constructor that has - in some form - always been a part of `std::vector`

```
explicit vector( size_type count ... );
```

And this one that was added in C++11

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Here, `vector<int>(5)` will call the first constructor and make a vector size 5.

And `vector<int>{5}` will call the second and make a vector of a single `5`.

Comment: what do you mean by "for any int"? does the syntax work only with int?

Comment: but `int` has a constructor. that you can call using `int()` and it is defined as making a zero initialized scalar. also as an exercize `new int()` always makes a zero new int, but `new int` makes an uninitialized int.

Comment: @v.oddou The rules of initialization govern different types of objects, including class types. An `int` is not a class type.

Answer (score 4):

In C++03 these are equivalent

```
const int a = 3;
const int a(3);
```

In C++11 the uniform initialization syntax was introduced and thus

```
const int a{3};
const int a = {3};
```

are allowed and are equivalent. However, the first two and the second two are NOT equivalent in all cases. `{}` doesn't allow narrowing. For example

```
int abc = {12.3f};
int xyz(12.3f);
```

Here's what GCC says

> error: type 'float' cannot be narrowed to 'int' in
>   initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
>
> ```
> int abc = {12.3f};
>            ^~~~~
> ```
>
> warning: implicit conversion from 'float' to 'int'
>   changes value from 12.3 to 12 [-Wliteral-conversion]
>
> ```
> int abc = {12.3f};
>           ~^~~~~
> ```

So the former begot an error, while the latter, just a warning.

**Caveats** in the uniform initialization syntax: If `a` was an object of a type accepting `std::initializer_list`, then `const MyClass a = { 1 }` would mean you're using that constructor and not the constructor taking a single `int` even if it was available (explained in Drew's anwer); If you want to choose the other constructor, then you've to use the `()` syntax. If `a` was an array, then you're using aggregate initialization.

[See here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) for various initialization options available in C++.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't support this syntax. It is however implemented in VS2013. The documentation for [initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wd1177%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the VS2012 tab doesn't describe any way of using direct initialization with braces (aka,[*`direct-list-initialization`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)). The following is MSVC's documentation on valid initializer syntax, it doesn't necessarily reflect what's valid from a language lawyer point of view.

> Declarators can specify the initial value for objects. The only way to
>   specify a value for objects of const type is in the declarator. The
>   part of the declarator that specifies this initial value is called the
>   initializer. There are two fundamental types of initializers:
>
> - Initializers invoked using the equal-sign syntax, including aggregate initializers:
>
> ```
>      = expression 
>     = { expression-list }
>     = { { expression-list}, {expression-list}, . . . }
> ```
>
> - Initializers invoked using function-style syntax:
>
> ```
>     ( expression )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Coding style is ultimately subjective, and it is highly unlikely that substantial performance benefits will come from it. But here's what I would say that you gain from liberal use of uniform initialization:

All 4 statements are valid and they are the same.

`const int a = 5;` -> Anyways, is the normal initialization syntax.
No need of explanation.!

`const int a(5);` -> function type initialization

`const int a = {5};` -> Array type initialization

`const int a{5};` -> It is not allowed in Visual Studio 2012, But, Initializer list support has been added in Visual Studio 2013. Hence const int a{5} , compiles fine with out any issues in VS2013.

But,
The only real power you give up is narrowing. You cannot initialize a smaller value with a larger one with uniform initialization.

```
int val{5.5};
```

That will not compile. You can do that with old-fashioned initialization, but not uniform initialization.